# How to view the contents of jar file in eclipse or jar-file-explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a project where i need to know the contents of jar file included in my web-project. I am using Eclipse juno. However Netbeans provides these features to view the contents of a jar-file. Please suggest me how to achieve this in eclipse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the project explorer, you should have something with an icon looking like a pile of book like those:

[image: classpath containers]

just expand the one containing your dependencies (probably labelled "Referenced Librairies") and you can browse as usual.

NB: you will probably need to specify where the sources are for each jars (right click on a jar > Properties > Java source attachment)

[image is courtesy of JBoss community]

Answer (score 3):

The `jar` will need to be added to the build path in the libraries tab, if it isn't already, in order to be viewable under referenced libraries

Answer (score 3):

Please use the Eclipse plugin **zipeditor** in order to view the content of jars, zips or wars: Enter update site: http://zipeditor.sourceforge.org/update and enjoy. That is the best choice so far to handle archives in Eclipse.

Comment: I pulled it from Eclipse Marketplace https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-zip-editor